# Simple proof involving inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof with inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286930/proof-with-inequalities)

I've just started reading a book on real analysis and a lot of my proofs reduce to proving this fact over and over again:

For all $\epsilon > 0$, if $a < b + \epsilon $ then $a \leq b$. How do I do this. Are there different ways of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate hmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement should probably read something like "If for all $\epsilon > 0$, $a < b + \epsilon$, then $a \le b$."

There are numerous ways to convince yourself of this.  One is to examine the contrapositive: if $a > b$, take $\epsilon > 0$ so that $a > b + \epsilon$ (i.e., $\epsilon < a-b$).  Then it's not true that $a < b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.  An easy modification of this will give you a proof by contradiction.